Cannot write file into hadoop3.3.6
I'm trying to use docker compose to build a hadoop cluster on my macbook(m1, apple silicon chip). I have expose the port of 9000 on docker container, here is my java code below:
package cn.dioxide;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class HadoopTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
            conf.set("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true");

            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

            Path dirPath = new Path("/user/test");
            if (fs.exists(dirPath)) {
                fs.delete(dirPath, true);
            }
            fs.mkdirs(dirPath);

            Path filePath = new Path("/user/test/test.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(filePath, true)));
            writer.write("Hello Hadoop!");
            writer.close();

            System.out.println("content: ");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(filePath)));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            fs.delete(filePath, true);
            System.out.println("file has been deleted");

            fs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


then the errors below occurred:
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/test/test.txt could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:912)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:621)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1094)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:3048)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy16.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)

I build a master image and a slave image with Dockerfile below:
Dockerfile-master and Dockerfile-slave
# Dockerfile-hadoop
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server wget iptables

COPY resources/jdk-11.0.23 /opt/jdk-11.0.23

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11.0.23
ENV PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

COPY resources/hadoop-3.3.6 /opt/hadoop-3.3.6
RUN mv /opt/hadoop-3.3.6 /opt/hadoop

RUN echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

ENV HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
ENV PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$PATH

RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys \
    && chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys \
    && echo "Host *\n    StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

COPY config/core-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
COPY config/hdfs-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
COPY config/yarn-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
COPY config/mapred-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

# if this file is master
COPY entrypoint/entrypoint-master.sh /entrypoint.sh
# if this file is slave
COPY entrypoint/entrypoint-slave.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

and my entrypoint-master.sh shell script is below:
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F

service ssh start

echo "export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH

if [ ! -d /hadoop/dfs/name ]; then
  hdfs namenode -format -force
fi

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-yarn.sh

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start secondarynamenode
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode

hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /

tail -f /dev/null

entrypoint-slave.sh:
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F

service ssh start

echo "export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH

if [ ! -d /hadoop/dfs/name ]; then
  hdfs namenode -format -force
fi

$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager

tail -f /dev/null

And my hadoop yml configuration file is below:
core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/root/hdfs/namenode</value>
        <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/root/hdfs/datanode</value>
        <description>DataNode directory</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
        <value>supergroup</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

mapred-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:10020</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.web.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:19888</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
        <value>$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

yarn-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-slave2:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

my docker-compose.yml is below:
version: '3.8'

services:
  hadoop-master:
    image: dioxidecn/hadoop-master-arm64:latest
    container_name: hadoop-master
    hostname: hadoop-master
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_name_dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/name
      - HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
      - YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=root
      - YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=root
    ports:
      - "9870:9870"   # NameNode Web UI
      - "8088:8088"   # ResourceManager Web UI
      - "9000:9000"   # HDFS NameNode
      - "50090:50090" # SecondaryNameNode Web UI
    networks:
      - hadoop_network

  hadoop-slave1:
    image: dioxidecn/hadoop-slave-arm64:latest
    container_name: hadoop-slave1
    hostname: hadoop-slave1
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_datanode_data_dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/data
      - NAMENODE_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR=hadoop-master
      - NAMENODE_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT=9000
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop-master:9000
      - HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
      - YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=root
      - YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=root
    depends_on:
      - hadoop-master
    networks:
      - hadoop_network

  hadoop-slave2:
    image: dioxidecn/hadoop-slave-arm64:latest
    container_name: hadoop-slave2
    hostname: hadoop-slave2
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
      - HDFS_CONF_dfs_datanode_data_dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/data
      - NAMENODE_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR=hadoop-master
      - NAMENODE_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT=9000
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://hadoop-master:9000
      - HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
      - HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
      - YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=root
      - YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=root
    depends_on:
      - hadoop-master
    networks:
      - hadoop_network

networks:
  hadoop_network:
    driver: bridge


Is there a specific reason not to use prebuilt Hadoop Ozone containers? Or Minio? HDFS isn't meant for small files like this. By the way, each of the slaves should not be attempting to reformat the namenode when they start

I just wanna try to verify that i can use hadoop docker compose to store files. so you mean that my test file is too small that cause this error?

Your error isn't related to the file size, no. It's saying the datanodes aren't running properly (check their logs, or the namenode UI for connection issues). But my main point is that Docker in general isn't a good option for running HDFS (or YARN), and expecting not multiple processes per container, when there are other distributed storage solutions that also can be written to from Java

Fine, i'll abort this. but if i using Ozone docker can resolve my problem?
